# Custom UITableView separator inset not working on iOS 8 with storyboards.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

All the `tableViews` of my app are not respecting the `property` `SeparatorInset`- `Custom` - `left = 0` on `storyBoard`.  It was all working fine on `iOS 7`, but not anymore.

When I implement the two below methods:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // iOS 7 
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    // iOS 8 
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // iOS 7 
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    // iOS 8 
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

It works correctly, I just don't understand why I can't keep setting this on `storyboard` which is much simpler.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

This code may help you.
Include both layoutMargins and separatorInset, to support both iOS versions 7,8
For iOS8:

First configure your table view as follows:

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(layoutMargins)]) {
    self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, configure the cell as follows:

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(layoutMargins)]) {
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

For version check you can use following things:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  }
#endif
```

Comment: Well, thanks. but in terms of code, my code works fine. I just wanted to be able to set the separator indent in storyboard, without any code. But it doesn't seem to work on iOS 8.

Comment: I'm having this issue, too. Did you file a radar that I can dupe?

Answer (score 1):

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Remove separator inset
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:") {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:") {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:") {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame) / 2, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame) / 2);